# New value is not getting updated in the jsf backing bean when submit button is clicked

Tags: jsf

I am creating a user manager page which updates and adds users in the same page.

Relevant parts of the view:

```
<h:outputText value="Existing User: "/>
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{userManagerBean.existingUser}" valueChangeListener="#{userManagerBean.updateDetails}" onchange="submit();">
    <f:selectItems value="#{userManagerBean.existingUserList}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputText value="User Name: "/>
<h:inputText binding="#{userManagerBean.userNameBinding}" value="#{userManagerBean.userName}"/>

<h:outputText value="Password: "/>
<h:inputSecret redisplay="true" binding="#{userManagerBean.passwordBinding}" value="#{userManagerBean.password}"/>

<h:outputText value="Accessibility: "/>
<h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" value="#{userManagerBean.selectedPagesList}" binding="#{userManagerBean.checkBoxBinding}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{userManagerBean.pagesList}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>

<h:commandButton action="#{userManagerBean.submitUser}" image="../images/submit.gif"/>
```

I am using value change listener in the dropdownlist. The bean is request scoped. The value change listener code is below:

```
public void updateDetails(ValueChangeEvent evt) {
    helper = new Helper();
    System.out.println(evt.getNewValue());
    UserManagerDAO userManagerDAO = new UserManagerDAO();
    List<String> userDetails = userManagerDAO.getUserDetails(evt.getNewValue().toString());
    //setUserName(getExistingUser());

    if (evt.getNewValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("select")) {
        passwordBinding.resetValue();
        userNameBinding.resetValue();
        checkBoxBinding.resetValue();
        //setUserName("finland");
    } else {
        passwordBinding.setValue(userDetails.get(0));
        userNameBinding.setValue(evt.getNewValue());
        checkBoxBinding.setValue(helper.splitStringAndAddToList(userDetails.get(1)));
    }
}
```

When I click the submit button, new username and password is not getting bind to the property, instead the value is returning null. If I remove the `if-else` block from the valuechange event code, everything works normal. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The components are processed in the order as they appear in the view. You're calling [`UIInput#setValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#setValue%28java.lang.Object%29) on components which aren't processed yet. Their values will be overridden afterwards with the actual submitted values. Rather use [`UIInput#setSubmittedValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#setSubmittedValue%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

Comment: Thanks you for answering my question. Sorry for the late reply.  Your answer solves the problem.  You rocks!!! Thanks again